# How to get host "client" initiator wwn's from FC SAN card & switch

Tags: linux, scsi, san

I saw an IBM San Storage and at Host alias creation page they can show you available host (client) initiators wwn's to choose.
And I wonder how they can find client initiator wwn's from storage?
I think they should be using a discover method for taking this information from SAN switch via fc but how?

If we simplify the question I'm the Storage System as you can see at below. And I want to discover available initiator port wwn number via FC port.

[image]

Do you know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about your question.

If you would like to know details of how devices registered in the fabric, you should read FC-protocol and FC-fabric specifications and start with [RSCN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_state_change_notification) topic - Registered State Change Notification. In your case, these notifications would be sent when you plug in/plug out a device into the switch port, notifying all members of the fabric-zone about the changes.

If you need to check a zone configuration and see which devices can access particular WWN, you have multiple choices depending on different circumstances. For example, on Brocade switch, you can run: `nszonemember <put-your-device-WWN-here>` to query the fabric nameserver about all other online devices that are zoned with the given WWN.